# Transfer material assignments to retopo'd mesh

Tags: materials

I can't find a way to transfer materials to my retopologized mesh. I have a terrain with multiple materials assigned to it, I've then retopologized it and want to transfer the per face material assignments to the new mesh... similar to how you can transfer vertex colours.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe that can be useful (or done) only in particular cases. Can you give more details?

Comment: What would you like to know? I'm looking for a way to project material assignments to another mesh like you can with vertex colours using the transfer mesh data modifier. Linking materials will create the material slots, but not assign it to the polys.

Comment: Well... highres poly to lowres poly won't match... that's why this operation does not exist. Or eventually for specific cases.

Comment: Yes, Maya has transfer shading sets which does exactly what I want. I was hoping there was a way to do something similar in Blender. Thanks